# Adding a key value pair to a list of dicts based on another list Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Sorry if the title is not clear, but here is what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a list of dicts :

```
l = [{'name': 'inAnalysis'}, {'name': 'inQuest'}, {'name': 'inDevelopment'}]
```

And a sort of translation table like this :

```
tr = {'inAnalysis' : 1, 'inDevelopment' : 2, 'inQuest' : 3}
```

I want to add the key value to `l` like this :

```
l = [{'name': 'inAnalysis', 'order' : 1},
     {'name': 'inQuest', 'order' : 3}, 
     {'name': 'inDevelopment', 'order' : 2}]
```

How can I match the value of l with the key of tr and get its value with the key `order` and add it to `l`? Any help would be appreciated. I'm using Python 2.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to dynamically generate the dictionaries like this

```
print [{"name":dic["name"], "order":tr[dic["name"]]} for dic in l]
```

**Output**

```
[{'name': 'inAnalysis', 'order': 1},
 {'name': 'inQuest', 'order': 3},
 {'name': 'inDevelopment', 'order': 2}]
```

Alternatively, you can use the following

```
for dic in l: dic["order"] = tr[dic["name"]]
```

this modifies the dictionaries in-place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the existing dictionaries in place (note that thefoutheye's solution makes new dictionaries which could concievably be a problem if something else in your code is holding a reference to the dictionaries in the list, rather than the list itself) you can do:

```
for my_dict in l:
    my_dict['order'] = tr[my_dict['name']]
```

Comment: @thefourtheye managed to update his solution 2 seconds before I hit the submit button on my solution :P